# How to get rid of the starting slash in URI or URL?

Tags: url, path, uri, absolute-path

I am using

```
URL res = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(dictionaryPath);
String path = res.getPath();
String path2 = path.substring(1);
```

because the output of the method getPath() returns sth like this:

```
 /C:/Users/......
```

and I need this

```
 C:/Users....
```

I really need the below address because some external library refuses to work with the slash at the beginning or with file:/ at the beginning or anything else.

I tried pretty much all the methods in URL like toString() toExternalPath() etc. and done the same with URI and none of it returns it like I need it. (I totally don't understand, why it keeps the slash at the beginning).

It is okay to do it on my machine with just erasing the first char. But a friend tried to run it on linux and since the addresses are different there, it does not work...

What should with such problem?

Comment: Strip the first character if path contains ":", for Christ's sake...

Comment: For Christ's sake, if you read the first three lines, you could see, that I am doing it already, but it is not helpful since - why should I repeat myself, just read the post......

Comment: you are doing it unconditionally. Whether I 'm telling you to do it, only if ":" is present

Comment: You can even go further and check for ":" especially in 3rd position.

Comment: well you did edit the comment, the : was not there before. Such answer however is alredy below.

Comment: Yes. And it's mine. Just tried to show it with code, if words are not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as UNIX paths are not supposed to contain drive letters, you may try this:

```
URL res = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(dictionaryPath);
String path = res.getPath();
char a_char = text.charAt(2);
if (a_char==':') path = path.substring(1);
```

Comment: thanks, I hope no other situation can occur with different OS.

Answer (score 10):

Convert the URL to a URI and use that in the File constructor:

```
URL res = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(dictionaryPath);
File file = new File(res.toURI());
String fileName = file.getPath();
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert to a URI, then use `Paths.get()`.

```
URL res = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(dictionaryPath);
String path = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toString();
```

Comment: Path.get may be deprecated in future, may be you could still use like this: String path 
= Path.of(res.toURI()).toString();

Comment: Btw, Path.of(...) is only available from Java11

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just format the string once you get it.

something like this:

path2= path2[1:];

Comment: Did you read the first three lines of this post? I am using it - I can not and do not want to use it since this attitude is not working on other than windows machine. + I believe there must exist a more elegant solution than this.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for one-line solution, so the best what i came up with was deleting it manually like this:

```
String url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(dictionaryPath).getPath().replaceFirst("/","");
```

In case if someone also needs to have it on different OS, you can make IF statement with

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```